# VirtualHost on Apache Server -- CentOS

Tags: apache, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

I am new to Apache server and would appreciate any help from you guys regards to VirtaulHost.

*Context:* I am setting up a CA/Web Server on CentOS 5.8 with Apache Server and I would like to have a public accessibility to my CRL

*Network Configurations*: eth0 - Private Interface: 10.10.10.2,                                 eth1 - Public Interface: 199.200.201.202 (fake one of course :P)

*Current Configuration* in "httpd.conf":

```
<VirtualHost 10.10.10.2:80>
    ServerAdmin a@aa.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog logs/CA-Test.abc.net
    CustomLog logs/CA_Custom_logs common
</VirtualHost>
<Directory />
      Order allow, deny
      Allow from all
      AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

*URL for CRL Location*: "CA-Test.abc.net\ca\crl\root.crl"

***Question\Problem***:  I would like to allow public access to the "\ca\crl" directory only, but not the contents under parent directories "\ca"

Should my VirtualHost Configuration to be:

```
<VirtualHost 199.200.201.202:80>
    ServerAdmin a@aa.com
    DocumentRoot /ca/crl/root.crl
    ErrorLog logs/CA-Test.abc.net
    CustomLog logs/CA_Custom_logs common
</VirtualHost>
```

If not, What should the correct DocumentRoot to be in this case? (*/var/www/html/ca/crl/root.crl??)*  How should I configure it correctly to allow external access to the correct URL of CRL location?

Thank you for your time and help.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding these to your httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost IP:80>
DocumentRoot /fullpath/to/ca/crl/
ServerName CA-Test.abc.net
</VirtualHost>
```

Now restart your httpd and try browsing the url

> http://CA-Test.abc.net/root.crl

Now public can't access the contents in the folder "ca". Let us know if that helped you.

Comment: Thank you Leo, I was out of town until Monday (8/5), it seems to fix my problem.  Thank you so much :)  I can download the CRL now

Comment: What exactly does the following do??  When do i need to specify the Directory??                                                        <Directory />
      Order allow, deny
      Allow from all
      AllowOverride all
</Directory>

Comment: The <Directory> directive allows you to apply certain directives to a particular directory only. Allow from all will allow everyone to access the directory. if you are using Deny from all, No one will be able to access. You can define the directory by "<Directory directory>". The same can be done by putting the "Allow/Deny from all in .htaccess"